# How can I pull variables out of a Static class?

Tags: java

As the title says I would like to pull some variables out of different classes. In class I was tasked with producing a magic square which isn't particularly hard to code so I thought I would make an interactive GUI for and because I had never coded with GUI before I had to learn how to use JLabel and JButton etc.

I believe I am successful with such learning this on my own being able to come up with a dialog box with the different sections which opens a prompt menu however I have added a confirm button which I would like to show what the user has entered. I have used JOptionPane.showMessageDialog to get user input and assigned it to a variable however I have no idea how to pull the variable out of it's class into the main where I can use it for other purposes. I have tried using this: classname.membername however I can't get it to work.

Code Below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.*;

public class Magic_SquareR {

    static boolean confirm = false;

    public Magic_SquareR() {
        gui();
    }

        public void gui() {


        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(350, 150);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        JButton b1 = new JButton("ML");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("TL");
        JButton b3 = new JButton ("BL");
        JButton b4 = new JButton ("TM");
        JButton b5 = new JButton ("MM");
        JButton b6 = new JButton ("BM");
        JButton b7 = new JButton ("TR");
        JButton b8 = new JButton ("MR");
        JButton b9 = new JButton ("BR");
        JButton b10 = new JButton ("Confirm");





        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;

        p.add(b2,c);
        b2.addActionListener(new Action());

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 100;
        p.add(b1,c);
        b1.addActionListener(new Action2());


        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = -100;
        p.add(b3,c);
        b3.addActionListener(new Action3());

        c.gridx = 100;
        c.gridy = 000;
        p.add(b4,c);
        b4.addActionListener(new Action4());

        c.gridx = 100;
        c.gridy = -100;
        p.add(b5,c);
        b5.addActionListener(new Action5());

        c.gridx = 100;
        c.gridy = -100;
        p.add(b6,c);
        b6.addActionListener(new Action6());


        c.gridx = -100;
        c.gridy = -100;
        p.add(b7,c);
        b7.addActionListener(new Action7());

        c.gridx = 200;
        c.gridy = -100;
        p.add(b8,c);
        b8.addActionListener(new Action8());

        c.gridx = 200;
        c.gridy = -100;
        p.add(b9,c);
        b9.addActionListener(new Action9());


        c.gridx = 100;
        c.gridy = 300;
        p.add(b10,c);
        b10.addActionListener(new Action10());

        f.add(p);

    }


static class Action implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

            String TL = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number from 1-10 for TL");
            int tl = Integer.parseInt(TL);


        }
    }

static class Action2 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

        String ML = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number from 1-10 for ML");
        int ml = Integer.parseInt(ML);

    }
}

static class Action3 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

        String BL = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number from 1-10 for BL");
        int bl = Integer.parseInt(BL);

    }
}

static class Action4 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

        String TM = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number from 1-10 for TM");
        int tm = Integer.parseInt(TM);


    }
}

static class Action5 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

        String MM = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number from 1-10 for MM");
        int mm = Integer.parseInt(MM);


    }
}

static class Action6 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

        String BM = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number from 1-10 for BM");
        int bm = Integer.parseInt(BM);


    }
}

static class Action7 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

        String TR = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number from 1-10 for TR");
        int tr = Integer.parseInt(TR);


    }
}

static class Action8 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

        String MR = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number from 1-10 for MR");
        int mr = Integer.parseInt(MR);


    }
}

public class Action9 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

        String BR = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number from 1-10 for BR");
        int br = Integer.parseInt(BR);


    }


}

public class Action10 implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to the end - This is where we check your answers");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "For BR your wrote " + Action9.BR);



    }


}

    public static void main(String args[]) {



        new Magic_SquareR();



        {




}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pull the variable out of its class"?

Comment: @James you can't, because they are not in the class, they are local variables in the methods

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and in particular [mcve] (note the "Minimal").

Comment: Oh my, so many things horrible with this code. I seriously suggest that you turn to the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ site and read all the swing tutorials, top to bottom. And before doing that, you better read the "basics" trail as well. You simply should not be using the *static* keyword **at all** for what you intend to do

Comment: And beyond that: improve the naming of your code. Dont use abbreviation that leave the reader wondering "what is TR, what is tr, ML and ml ..." . NEVER ever start "numbering" button1, button2, button3. Use names that **mean** something.

Comment: Thanks for the criticism - I deeply mean this as I am an inexperienced coder and I aspire to be a great one so information like this really helps. I'll take on GhostCat's advice and do further tutorials on 'swing' and and also take care in naming variables.

Answer (score 0):

All you do with current values is assigning them to local variables (which disappear after method returns). The easiest way to achieve access to them would be declaring them as astatic variables inside Magic_SquareR class.

```
public class Magic_SquareR {

    static boolean confirm = false;
    static int actionResult1;
    //other results

    public Magic_SquareR() {
        gui();
    }

    public void gui() {
        // ...
    }

    static class Action implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            String TL = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number from 1-10 for TL");
            Magic_SquareR.actionResult1 = Integer.parseInt(TL);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Magic_SquareR();            
        System.out.println(actionResult1);
    }
}
```

Please mind that it is really 'ugly' way to achieve that (you should generaly avoid using static variables), but it will do.

If you wish to make it more professional declare Action classes in separate files, give them local variables with input values and return a list of these values from gui() method:

```
public class Action implements ActionListener {

    int actionResult;

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            String TL = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number from 1-10 for TL");
            actionResult = Integer.parseInt(TL);
    }
{
```

And in gui() it would look something like:

```
//return list of input values instead of void
List<Integer> gui() {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
    //...
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 100;
    p.add(b1,c);

    //Assign action to variable so you can access it later
    Action action = new Action();
    b1.addActionListener(action);
    list.add(action.actionResult);
    //...
    return list;

}
```